# Am I doing anything wrong by getting a greeting card for an employee who is leaving?

Tags: politics, people-management

An employee gave her two weeks notice. This employee had worked for the company for 4 years then left the company. Then came back to the company after 6 months into a new position. Now one year later, the employee is leaving again. Since I have worked for this company, about 7 months. I have seen employees sign a going away card for the leaving employee and give a gift. I have gotten close to the employee who is leaving. So I asked the manager if we would be doing anything or getting anything for the leaving employee. His response was no because this employee left the company once before. I feel that was a little cold and I feel the leaving employee should at least get a card. I plan to buy a goodbye greeting card for the leaving employee and pass it around for employees to sign. I plan to not give it to the manager. Am I doing anything wrong by getting the card? The card would be paid for from my own pocket. If I had known the Manager would react like that. I never would have asked him.

Comment: "I have seen employees sign a going away card for the leaving employee" So why not just sign this card? Or did you mean you've seen this for other leaving employees?

Comment: Do you know if there was any bad feeling or dispute between this employee and your manager? If there was, and it's related to the employee leaving, your manager might be touchy about this because they don't want you to shine a light on the situation.

Comment: Your title says 'greeting card', I thought you were being clever by suggesting she would be back with another new job again..

Comment: "*So I asked the manager if we would be doing anything or getting anything for the leaving employee*" Is that what you literally asked? Because if that's what you literally said I'd say no too. How am I supposed to know you're not talking dinner, party or gift?

Comment: I guess I didn't think of it like that. All I was thinking was maybe a card and maybe a $50 Starbucks gift card. Now I can see that maybe I was thinking of something more elaborate.

Comment: @DiligentWorker25 Yeah. It's like if I want to go to lunch with a bunch of coworkers. We don't ask. We just go. But if I ask my manager if a bunch of coworkers could go to lunch together he is going to interpret that as asking the company to pay, because why else would I ask? Personally, I think the company paying for a $50 gift card would be too much since this is the employee's second time leaving, and a card is so cheap that there's no reason to ask the company to pay (which, incidentally, is a large part of why it would not even occur to me if an employee asked me that)

Comment: I can see that now. I decided to get a card only and just walk it around the office getting different people to sign it. The employee leaving is popular and many people thanked me for including them. I did not give the card to the Manager to sign. He made his stance, so I didn't think he would be interested.

Comment: @DiligentWorker25 It only makes sense to ask people who care anyways.

Comment: I ended up getting the card and just walking it around getting people to sign it. I will leave it on his desk on the day he is leaving. That's all.

Comment: If I had never asked the manager and just got the card and passed it around to sign, this would not be an issue. In one of the posts, someone made the point that maybe my manager thought I wanted to take the employee for lunch or some big gesture. That was not my thinking at all. So now I can see why the manager said no. I don't think a greeting card only will be harmful. And it's paid for from my pocket.

Answer (score 66):

You are making a mistake by doing this behind the manager's back. The manager might feel disrespected after you asked and ignored the answer, or even that you are challenging the manager's authority by doing something the manager decided wasn't earned.

If you want to get her the card out of your own pocket, that's fine, but at least tell the manager your intentions if you want to pass it around, allow the manager to dissuade you, and offer the manager to sign it. If the manager pushes back again, just present the card with only your remarks.

Comment: I'd argue this is also a "don't know the circumstances" - if coworker has been asked to leave or is being pushed out the door, you might not celebrate in any way

Comment: I'd agree with this answer considering the limited information we have. But actually we have no idea if the manager's opinion is "Naahhh.... we gave her one already", or "It's strict company policy: One leaving card per person", or the manager's personality at all, or the mood / culture in the company. There are a lot of nuances involved in a question like that probably can't be conveyed on an anonmymous public forum.

Comment: It may be that the manager just doesn't like this employee and was annoyed that she was rehired, but would be in full support of a card for other employees leaving a 2nd time. Who knows... Fully support the OP giving a goodbye card signed only by him/herself.

Answer (score 17):

Nope not doing anything wrong. You've done it of your own volition and out of your own pocket.

I understand the manager's reason(s) - if they've left previously and come back - it's a little petty, but I get it.

You are fine though.

Comment: Can you explain? I don't get the Manager's reasoning.

Comment: Each person gets 1 leaving gift.  You can't "farm" gifts from the company by joining and leaving in this way (of course there are other considerations as to why someone may not want to/be able to do so, but anyway the manager says they can't, absent those other concerns)

Comment: In addition to @Ertai87 answer - there's a length of time aspect - when I left my last company, I had been there for 6-7 years. I got a nice company meal and a plane ticket to fly down to our capitol city to see one of my favourite extreme metal bands - about $300 worth of present. If I'd come back and only worked for a year, it would be extremely presumptious to expect the same treatment.

Comment: I read this as though your coworker had been gone for 6 months, and back for 6 months at first, which as a manager would have been super annoying. But, yeah, you can't really get frustrated at people who leave after a year.

Comment: @Ertai87 I would hardly call getting a card with some well meaning messages a "gift" worth farming. We're talking about a few cents of whatever is the local currency.

Comment: @DiligentWorker25 Usually people who left and came back were given a _generous_ raise or bonus to get them to come back. If they're now leaving again quickly, especially if it's after exactly one year (a lot of bonuses have conditions like you must stay one year) it's not a good look.

Comment: @user3067860 So they shouldn't be considered as persons worthy of a few cents spent on them and a token of gratitude for the months working alongside them? This is so petty I can't even begin to describe it. You also make it sound like someone selling their services (employees) are getting something they're not worthy of.

Comment: @Jonast92 It's not really the card, but I'd rather have the bonus go to someone who stayed and worked hard and didn't have a foot out the door the whole time. It's like parents who spend all the time and attention on the "bad kid" and just ignore the "good kid" who never causes trouble. It reinforces the whole environment of you have to threaten to quit if you ever want to get a good raise, because you're never getting one otherwise.

Comment: "it's a little petty" - more than petty, it sounds to me like the manager had some dispute with this person (probably part of the reason they're leaving relatively soon), there's a bad cloud in the air, and the manager doesn't want anyone shining a light on the situation.

Comment: @user3067860 I think in fairness the whole "you have to threaten to quit to get a raise" is more the fault of the employer for not seeing that long term employees should be valued and rewarded - I think that's where I'd get worked up, rather than at this

Comment: @terdon OP didn't ask the manager about a card though. If OP's words are accurate OP asked about "doing anything or getting anything". If I heard this, a card would not be the first thing that would come to my mind.

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8 See my above comment.

Comment: @Jonast92 See my above comment.

Comment: @DKNguyen the OP's words are: *I feel that was a little cold and I feel the leaving employee should at least get a card. I plan to buy a goodbye greeting card for the leaving employee and pass it around for employees to sign.*

Comment: @terdon The manager isn't a mind reader. What you quoted is not what the OP actually said to the manager. What the OP actually asked was: "*if we would be doing anything or getting anything for the leaving employee*". If I was manager and an employee asked me that, a card would not be what I had in mind. I would interpret that as a request for me to organize a dinner or gift, for an employee that is re-leaving the company, no less. I'd say no to that too and it would be completely reasonable.

Answer (score 12):

I understand how you feel, but ultimately the only reason why I would do this would be if I was personally close to the departing employee.  I would not give a gift to a random coworker, particularly against the wishes of my manager and the company at-large, and I would certainly not involve other coworkers in doing so.

If you are personally close to this coworker, by all means, buy this person a gift or a card and give it to them, in person, and in private.

Comment: I am close to the person. I made the mistake of going to the manager first. His reaction was not what I was expecting.

Comment: In that case, give them a gift as a friend if you wish, but make it clear that it is not from the company, but from you personally as a friend.  There's nothing wrong with a friend giving a gift to another friend.

Comment: Make the gift personal and inexpensive. I once gave a jar of homemade jam in the same situation. He almost got tears in his eyes.

Comment: @DiligentWorker25 your comment would be an _excellent_ addition to your original question. Please edit that info in so everyone sees it when they read your question.

Answer (score 8):

I understand why you want to do this, but you shouldn't. Two different relationship dynamics are in conflict here:

**(A)** You and this individual as friends.

**(B)** You and this individual as employees of the company under a common manager.

As a professional you need to clearly separate those out, and act appropriately.

> I plan to buy a goodbye greeting card... The card is paid for from my own pocket.

This is completely fine. You're doing a nice thing for a friend. Relationship A dominates. Relationship B has little relevance. For example you doing this outside working hours and even premises would not affect the gesture - in fact you may well consider doing that!

> (I plan to) pass it around for employees to sign. I plan to not give it to the manager.

With this, though, relationship B dominates. You've involved other employees of the company as a collective, and by definition will likely have to do so in working hours and/or premises. Worse, you've indirectly involved the manager too by defying their wishes.

It'll still be a nice gesture from their point of view, of course, but relationship B just makes it overall inappropriate, and a negative for you, given the circumstances.

Your 7 month tenure at the company is a factor here too - you've likely not yet built the social capital at the company necessary to counterbalance any negative effect on you, in a way a more tenured employee may be able to.

Really, I think it's unwise to do this. I'd advise only doing the first part of buying a personal card/gift yourself and leave the gesture at that.

Answer (score 2):

> So I asked the manager if we would be doing anything or getting anything for the leaving employee.

If this is literally what you asked then the manager probably interpreted that as requesting the company to organize a dinner or gift. What other reason could there possible be to bring it up with a manager? For an employee leaving for the second time, it would be completely reasonable to say no to that.

A card is so inexpensive that there's little reason to get the manager or company involved which would be why it might not even occur to the manager that was what you had in mind.